# std::map initialization crashing on iPhone device, but not in simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, stl

I've tried turning on the `Call C++ Default Ctors/Dtors in Objective-C` flag but I'm still getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when I first try to access my map:

```
(*[TextureBatcher getSharedTextureBatcher].getMap)[texID].vertexCount=0;
(*[TextureBatcher getSharedTextureBatcher].getMap)[texID].indexCount=0;
```

getMap just returns a reference to my map:

```
-(VertexMap *) getMap{
    return &texMap;
}
```

And a VertexMap is a typedef of a std::map:

```
typedef std::map<GLuint, VertexInfo> VertexMap;
```

Not sure why this is failing on device and not in the simulator, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Just so we're clear:

```
(*[TextureBatcher getSharedTextureBatcher].getMap)[texID].vertexCount=0;
```

If theMap[texID] does not exist, the above line will cause a VertexInfo object to be constructed (with the default constructor, VertexInfo()).  Is this what you're intending?

Perhaps the underlying std::map is implemented differently on the device, preventing this kind of initialisation?

Are you sure you set the **Call C++ Default Ctors/Dtors in Objective-C** flag on the Device target, not just the Simulator target?

Generally, the pattern is to use pointers here (C++) so you'd end up with:

```
typedef std::map<GLunit, VertexInfo*> VertexMap;
VertexMap theMap;

theMap[0] = new VertexInfo(...);

//  now operate on theMap[0] normally
```

Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Yes, I do want the default constructor to be called.  Yes, Default Ctor/Dtor is turned on in the device target.  Still scratching my head unfortunately :-\

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?